# Help understanding VCF schematic

Tags: audio, filter, active-filter

I'm trying to build an adjustable active filter for an audio mixer and stumbled upon this design.

[image]

I'm completely lost. I understand first order passive filters and Sallen Key's.

Comment: It would be far better to look at designs using voltage-controlled amplifiers, like the LM13700 if you can get it.

Answer (score 1):

The heart of the design is a twin T notch filter: -

[image]

This type of circuit normally rejects a small band of frequencies but, when placed within the negative feedback loop of an op-amp, The lack of negative feedback at those frequencies means the gain of the op-amp circuit is very high - thus a band pass fitler is created.

The LED is acting as a voltage controlled resistor varying R/2 in my circuit. This of course pulls the centre frequency up or down. It's a bit crude but relies on the slope of the LED V-I characteristic: -

[image]

Look at the red curve - with barely a volt across the LED the slope of the curve is very low but progressively gets more as the voltage is increased. If you translate this to V/I (resistance), you get a variable resistor controlled by a DC voltage. There will be a little distortion of the superimposed AC but as it is an "effect" it probably doesn't matter a great deal.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I think what this is doing is adjusting the bias current of the LED, which changes the ac impedance seen at the feedback node. Considering that even the author doesn't think much of this filter ("decent fake lowpass response") I'm not sure it's the kind of think you want in an audio mixer.